# Deleting a User relation using Rails Models and Interactors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a question regarding the deletion of a User. Note that I'm not using Devise since my app is an API.

**What I need to do**

So I have a User model, I can delete this `User` with no issues. The user `belongs to many` other associations regarding `Bank Accounts`, `Transactions`, you name it.

When I delete the `User`, it's able to be deleted but its associations are not. Note that I'm using `soft_deletion` which means it gets in an `INACTIVE` state. And by saying that the "associations aren't being deleted" means that I just need to `DISABLE` specific associations when the `User` has been deleted or gets `INACTIVE`

**What I currently have**

**user.rb** model file

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :bank_accounts

    def soft_deletion!
        update!(status: "DELETED",
        deleted_at: Time.now)
     end
 end
```

**delete_user.rb** interactor file

```
module UserRequests
 class DeleteUser < BaseInteractor 
   def call
    require_context(:id)
    remove_user
    context.message = 'user record deleted'
   end
    
    def remove_user
      user = context.user
      context.user.soft_deletion! #<- This is the method I have on my model, which works!
      
     #below I removed all user invites in case there's one
      user_invite = UserInvite.joined.where(
        "lower(email) = '#{user.email.downcase}'"
      )&.first
      user_invite&.update(status: "CANCELLED")
      return if user.user.present?
      user.update!(status: "INACTIVE")
    end
  end
end
```

So giving a bit more context of what happened up there. My App is an API, on my frontend I remove the user and it actually works, and so what I need to do next is delete the user AND delete a bank_account that's associated with my user.

**What I've been trying to do** (This fails so hard, and I need some help )

I honestly don't know how to interact between interactions on Rails, that's the reason of my question here.

**delete_user.rb** interactor file

```
module UserRequests
 class DeleteUser < BaseInteractor 
   def call
    require_context(:id)
    remove_user
    
   soft_delete_transaction_account #method to delete bank account
    context.message = 'user record deleted'
   end

    #since there's an association I believe in adding a method to verify if there's a bank 
    account.
    def soft_delete_bank_account
      context.account = context.user.bank_accounts.find_by_id(context.id)
      fail_with_error!('account', 'does not exist') unless
        context.account.present?

      context.account.update!(deleted: true,
        deleted_at: Time.now)
     end       

    
    def remove_user
      user = context.user
      context.user.soft_deletion! #<- This is the method I have on my model, which works!
      context.user.soft_delete_transaction_account #<- Then I add that method here so the bank account can be deleted while the user gets deleted!
     #below I removed all user invites in case there's one
      user_invite = UserInvite.joined.where(
        "lower(email) = '#{user.email.downcase}'"
      )&.first
      user_invite&.update(status: "CANCELLED")
      return if user.user.present?
      user.update!(status: "INACTIVE")
    end
  end
end
```

**ERROR LOG of my code:**

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `soft_delete_bank_account' for #<User:0x00007f8284d660b0>:
  app/interactors/admin_requests/delete_user.rb:47:in `remove_user'
  app/interactors/admin_requests/delete_user.rb:9:in `call'
  app/controllers/admin_controller.rb:18:in `destroy'
```

I would appreciate your help on this!

Comment: Looks like you're calling the `soft_delete_bank_account` method on an `Employee` object. The code fails since the method isn't defined in the `Employee` class. Can you post the code invoking the `soft_delete_bank_account` method?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan sorry I misspled those logs. I just renamed them ( I have autocrrect in my computer, sorry lol)

Comment: The error log posted in the question mentions `soft_delete_bank_account` being called on a `User` object (which was in your previous edit, `Employee`). But your code doesn't call that method at all. And the `soft_delete_transaction_account` gets called on both the `DeleteUser` and `User` objects which doesn't seem right. Can you post the actual code you've got?